# JQueryMobile Popup with Header displays back button

Tags: jquery-mobile, popup

I have a button that calls a popup:

```
<a id="clearAll" href="#confirmDelete" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-role="button" data-mini="true"  data-theme="c" data-transition="pop" >Clear Error</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="confirmDelete" data-overlay-theme="a" data-add-back-btn="false" data-theme="c" style="max-width: 400px;" class="ui-corner-all" >
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-top" data-add-back-btn="false">
        <h1>Clear Log?</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content">
        <h3 class="ui-title">Are you sure you want to delete all the entries in this log?</h3>
        <p>This action cannot be undone.</p>
        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <a href="#" data-role="button"data-theme="b">Delete</a>  
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">Cancel</a>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If the link that calls this page does not contain data-ajax="false", the popup contains a back button even with data-add-back-btn="false".  How do I get rid of the button?  I do want the back button on the main page, just not on the popup.

Comment: Hi! What version of jQuery Mobile are you using?

Comment: I get similar, but inconsistent behavior. The docs say to nest the popup div inside the div[data-role="page"] with the link that calls the popup.
In a regular "page", the popup will have a black "Back" button.
In a "dialog" page, the popup may or may not get a small "X" button in the left corner of the header, but never the black "Back" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay @Christine, like I commented, the popup even gives different kinds of back/close button to a header inside a popup. But the solution is easy: add the following to your custom css file (make sure that file is referenced after the jquerymobile css file):

```
div[data-role="popup"] div[data-role="header"] .ui-btn {
    display: none;
}
```

This should hide all buttons inside the header bars of all popups. Customize at your pleasure!